# C reading bmp files

Tags: c, bmp

I'm trying to read in a bmp file to my program and I'm having some issues. After reading in the file if i tell it to print the pBmp->header.fileSize it says 16 but if i look at it in a hex editor the file size portion has F6 7A 10 00 if I modify the value to the correct file size in the hex it will say F6 7A F6 7A 10 00 but that is running into the resv1 which should always be zero. I know that this is only reading in 1 pixel of data another issue I have is when I try to use a while loop to read in the pixels until the end of file I get a segmentation fault. I've literally spent hours googling trying to figure this out but I'm not having much luck.

```
// The BMPHEADER structure.
typedef struct {
    byte        sigB;
    byte        sigM;
    int32_t     fileSize;
    int16_t     resv1;
    int16_t     resv2;
    int32_t     pixelOffset;
} tBmpHeader;

// The BMPINFOHEADER structure.
typedef struct {
    int32_t     size;
    int32_t     width;
    int32_t     height;
    int16_t     colorPlanes;
    int16_t     bitsPerPixel;
    byte        zeros[24];
} tBmpInfoHeader;

typedef uint8_t byte;

typedef struct {
    byte blue;
    byte green;
    byte red;
} tPixel;

// A BMP image consists of the BMPHEADER and BMPINFOHEADER structures, and the 2D pixel array.
typedef struct {
    tBmpHeader      header;
    tBmpInfoHeader  infoHeader;
    tPixel          **pixel;
} tBmp;

tPixel **BmpPixelAlloc(int pWidth, int pHeight)
{
    tPixel **pixels = (tPixel **)malloc (pHeight * sizeof(tPixel *));
    for (int row = 0; row < pHeight; ++row)
    {
        pixels[row] = (tPixel *)malloc(pWidth * sizeof(tPixel));
    }

    printf("pixelAlloc\n"); 

    return pixels;
}

pBmp->pixel = BmpPixelAlloc(pBmp->infoHeader.width, pBmp->infoHeader.height);
if(FileRead(file, &pBmp->pixel, sizeof(tPixel), 1)!=0)
{ 
    errorCode = ErrorFileRead;
}
```

Comment: can you show the complete code? you don't have a main, FileRead isn't defined, you don't show where you check the header.FileSize, you don't show tBmpHeader, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the padding of the structure for the header. You may find that the compiler has aligned the `fileSize` value in the `struct` to a 4-byte boundary within the structure. You can see this if you put in some debug `printf`'s of the structure element addresses.

I ran an example using your `struct` here:

```
typedef struct {
    byte        sigB;
    byte        sigM;
    int32_t     fileSize;
    int16_t     resv1;
    int16_t     resv2;
    int32_t     pixelOffset;
} tBmpHeader;

tBmpHeader hdr;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(tBmpHeader) );
    printf("%p hdr\n", &hdr);
    printf("%p sigB\n", &hdr.sigB);
    printf("%p sigM\n", &hdr.sigM);
    printf("%p fileSize\n", &hdr.fileSize);
    printf("%p resv1\n", &hdr.resv1);
    printf("%p resv2\n", &hdr.resv2);
    printf("%p pixelOffset\n", &hdr.pixelOffset);
}
```

With the output:

```
16
0x8049788 hdr
0x8049788 sigB
0x8049789 sigM
0x804978c fileSize
0x8049790 resv1
0x8049792 resv2
0x8049794 pixelOffset
```

There is a 4-byte offset between the beginning of `hdr` and the `fileSize` element, so there are two bytes of padding before `fileSize`.

The thing to do is read the header a date item at a time. You can maintain some "structure" to the code by encapsulating the reads in a single function (e.g., "readBmpHeader(...)"). You can keep the `struct` but read each field separately. So, you would do (I leave off the return value checks for clarity of example):

```
FileRead(file, &pBmp->header.sigB, sizeof(byte), 1)
FileRead(file, &pBmp->header.sigB, sizeof(byte), 1)
FileRead(file, &pBmp->header.fileSize, sizeof(int32_t), 1)
FileRead(file, &pBmp->header.resv1, sizeof(int16_t), 1)
FileRead(file, &pBmp->header.resv2, sizeof(int16_t), 1)
FileRead(file, &pBmp->header.pixelOffset, sizeof(int32_t), 1)
```

Comment: Looks like you're right, i'm not sure what to do about it though.

Comment: ah it works now, do you think that's why i was having the problem with looping too?

Comment: @Covertpyro you'll need to split up your pixel row reads since your separate `malloc` addresses won't be in contiguous memory.

Comment: yeah I was getting the right pixel data for the first pixel before but now that the header is working the first pixel is wrong. a tutor told me to use a while(!feof) loop to fill the array but that is giving me a segmentation fault.

Comment: See the code sample. You do need to read in the reserved values to get past them. The `while ( !feof(...) )` may be failing you due to the fact that your pixel data is not contiguous. So you'd be overwriting unallocated memory. In addition, you can't read your `tPixel` as a structure. You need one byte at a time, just like with the header. You might want to update your code and post a new problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

You should never use direct I/O with structures: just because you've declared your `struct` in the same order as the BMP headers, there's no guarantee that your compiler has the fields end-to-end with nothing in between.

Compilers frequently adhere to a platform's alignment restrictions, which might cause them to add padding bytes between fields to make sure e.g. a large field's starting address is aligned.

You need to either use compiler-specific magic to force the structure to be "packed", or byte-by-byte I/O into the structure.