# reading a bmp header in C

Tags: c, bmp

I wrote a program to read a BMP file header.
The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned short BYTE;
typedef unsigned int DWORD;

typedef struct _WinBMPFileHeader {
  WORD   FileType;
  DWORD  FileSize;
  WORD   Reserved1;
  WORD   Reserved2;
  DWORD  BitmapOffset;
} WINBMPFILEHEADER;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  WINBMPFILEHEADER *header = NULL;
  FILE *fptr;
  size_t bytes_read;

  if (argc == 2) {
    fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    bytes_read = fread(header, sizeof(WINBMPFILEHEADER), 1, fptr);
  }
  else
    printf("The number of parameters is wrong.\n");

  return 0;

}
```

When I run the program I have a segmentation fault because of fread.
What is the reason of this fault?

Comment: you simply assume the file got opened correctly. never assume success with external resources. if fopen() fails, it returns null. if you then try to use that null as a file pointer, you will get a segmentation fault.

Comment: `fread` reads a binary stream, but your `fopen` does says `'r'` instead of `'rb'`. Also, you don't check for errors after trying to open the file, so how do you *know* the file actually opened successfully and is ready to be read?

Comment: Probably a dublicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745658/c-reading-bmp-files

Comment: I know that the program fails at that point because I checked with the printf but I omitted them just to save space. Additionally, also gdb tells that the problem is in fread. Eventually, I just tried with fopen(argv[1], "rb") and it fails again.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this

```
WINBMPFILEHEADER *header = NULL;
...
bytes_read = fread(header, sizeof(WINBMPFILEHEADER), 1, fptr);
```

The segmentation fault is because you are passing `NULL` to the function. You must allocate memory for `header`, perhaps

```
header = malloc (sizeof(WINBMPFILEHEADER));
```

Also you have a declaration error as a separate issue:

```
typedef unsigned short BYTE;
```

should be

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```

Finally you must make sure you don't have **endian** issues with any 2 or 4 (I don't think there are any 8) byte fields, a bit off-topic.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I have a question about the declaration. Why is "typedef unsigned short BYTE;" the right declaration?

Comment: If this answer was correct please "accept" it. As to your comment question, it is a "typo" or "copy/pasta" error. Why would you define two types to be the same? Look at the WORD `typedef` above. BYTE will never be `short`.

Comment: I think you mean "Why is `typedef unsigned short BYTE;` the *wrong* declaration?"

Answer (score 2):

try this one, its a sipmle one i use

```
synHead reader(FILE* img) { 
synHead info;
fseek(img, 10, 0);
fread(&info.D, 1, 4, img);

fseek(img, 18, 0);
fread(&info.W, 1, 4, img);

fseek(img, 22, 0);
fread(&info.H, 1, 4, img);

return(info);
```